# DIV não aperece no browser CHROME e IE

Tags: css, html5, div

Estou a tentar resolver um problema de *CSS* no meu desenvolvimento:

**HTML:**

Criei uma DIV responsive com 1 COLUNA (GRID de 6) para uma secção de conteúdo especifica.
Já coloquei texto dentro desta.

**CSS:**

Criei uma class para estilizar essa DIV

```
#saldos{
    background-color:FFFFFF;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
}
```

O resultado não é nenhum no browser, apenas aparece o texto, mas sem fundo.
Penso que alguma class PAI, está a impedir o resultado que pretendo n o FILHO.

Como descubro o que está acontecer? Já estive no `inspect element` a ver o que pode estar a influenciar este bloqueio de *CSS*.

Comment: Deves ter `#` antes do código da côr, testa com `background-color: #FFFFFF;` e dá-lhe um `width` também, caso não tenha conteúdo.

Comment: Muiiiiiito Obrigada Sergio :) Está resolvido.

Comment: marque a resposta do @Sergio com o check verde por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O formato da côr no CSS está em [hexadecimal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripleto_hexadecimal#Hex_triplet), mas ter um erro de escrita. Deves ter `#` antes do código da côr, testa com `background-color: #FFFFFF;` e assim a sintaxe já fica correta.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kLzsv34r/